# Uncommon? Call Forwarding Rule

Tags: asterisk

I'm looking to have my FreePBX server forward incoming calls to a phone number that it pulls from a mysql database. The only thing unique about how I need it to forward calls is that there will be multiple numbers located in the database, and I need my PBX to choose one of these numbers purely at random and forward the call there. Is there a native function in FreePBX or Asterisk that allows for pulling a number at random from a database and forwarding the call there? Help is much appreciated

Comment: I think the closest you'd get with an off the shelf FreePBX solution would be creating a queue with the random strategy for dialing an extension. And then you'd add the extensions to that queue. When a call comes in you would direct it to the call queue.

Answer (score 0):

There are no module like that. You can write it or ask someone write it.

You also can use extension with type-> custom and dialline like s@special-dial. After that put in context special-dial into file extensions_custom.conf which will access database.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+extensions.conf

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+func_odbc